# joomla 2.5 - removing frontpage content block for joomlaxtc website

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have tried to look around all over the place to edit the joomla frontpage. Im using a template from joomlaxtc which is another reason why I believe im having trouble as the coding is a little different.

What I'm trying to achieve is remove the component or article area for my Joomla 2.5 front page.

here is the website

http://colmandesigns.123abc.co.nz/tyrelink/

as you can see the 'coming soon' white text box I want to remove however I only want to remove it for the front page not the rest of the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the "coming soon" bit, then go to the module that holds the "coming soon" bit.  On the left, you should see "Module assignment."  Click that, and choose "no" for `Home Page: assign to`.

[This video](http://people.joomla.org/videos/adeelch/video/861-how-to-see-template-positions-in-joomla-25-a-1617.html) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get your site to come up, but the home page of a joomla site is generally determined by the default item on your main menu.

From the admin Control Panel:

1. Choose Menu->Main Menu
2. Locate the menu item on the list that has a star in the "Home" column
3. Click on the menu item, and from what you see, determine what the article is
4. Go to that article, and edit there.

This presumes that your home page is an article, as is the case in a standard Joomla site, and doesn't account for anything your template may do in terms of features or settings,

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to the template manager and go to the advanced parameters and see the show component on home page and select NONE

Answer (score 0):

Your template may have configuration to hide main content block from frontpage but if not then it can be hidden by using code block below on index.php or your php file which will define template layout.

```
<?php if (JRequest::getVar('view') != 'featured'): ?>
<div id="maincontentdiv"><jdoc:include type="component" /></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```